# .NET MVC routing in RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "PATIENT", new { Patient = v });
```

("v" is an instance of a Patient class)

I'm hoping that I am essentially transporting an instance "v" of the "Patient" class to the "PatientController"?

I want to now access the data in "v".

Is it correct to make inside PATIENTController:

```
public IActionResult Index(Patient p){}
```

And now in the function body I have full access to "v" from the other Controller??

edit: here is the model code

```
public class Patient
{

    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }//For MongoDB
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Encounter> Encounters { get; set; }

    public Patient() { }
    public Patient(ObjectId id, string name, int age) {
        _id = id;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would only work if `Patient` contains simple propertes (if any properties are complex objects or collections it will fail), and you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception. But the correct code would be `return RedirectToAction("Index", "PATIENT",  v );` and `public IActionResult Index(Patient p){}` but the correct approach is to pass the ID of the model and get it again in the GET method.

Comment: Okay thanks, so if I do it the correct approach, then a string called "id" , then RedirectToAction("Index", "PATIENT", id);  and   Index(string id){}   ??

Comment: Show you Patient model code.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct approach

Comment: So when do we use something like "new { Patient = v }" in the RedirectToAction?  It's just a key-value pair right?

Answer (score 0):

remove controller sufix in your code.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "PATIENT", new { Patient = v });
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Patient = v });
```

The patient value has send as a query string values.

if its above code is not working .you use tempdata .And assign the value to tempdata.

```
TempData["patient"] = v
```

And then access the tempdata in your index method

```
Patient pt = (Patient)TempData["patient"];
```

Comment: Not an answer to any question OP is looking to have answered.